# How do I get the creation date of a mentioned player [DISCORD.JS V13]

Tags: javascript

*Note: I'm using **v13** of "discord.js".*

---

**This is the command that I currently have:**

```
if (command === 'check') {
    if (message.member.permissions.has(['KICK_MEMBERS'])) {
      let mentioned = message.mentions.users.first();
      let name = mentioned.username

      message.channel.send(`Account name: ${name}.`) 
      message.channel.send(`Account ID: ${mentioned.user.}`)

    } else if (!message.member.permissions.has(
    ['KICK_MEMBERS'])) {
      message.channel.send('You do not have permissions to do this command!')

    } else {
      message.channel.send('An error has occured while attempting to run the command.') 
    }   }
```

`The let mentioned = message.mentions.users.first(); gets the mentioned user`

---

**This is how you say the command:**

`!check @Downrest`

---

Okay, so here's my question.
How do I get the creation date of **`mentioned`**?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/general/welcome), you can see in the [User class](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/User) that you have a property called [createdAt](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/User?scrollTo=createdAt) that returns a [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date), so `mentioned.createdAt` should return the creation date of the user.